# Position div on top of other div next to border

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to place a div on top of another div next to the parent div's border, see
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcvh6wo5/). My issue is that when I zoom in/out in the browser it will be a gap between the border and the green div. Any input on how to solve this?

Current code:

CSS:

```
#small_box
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: green;
}

#border_box
{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    border:5px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="border_box"><div id="small_box"></div></div>
```

[image: Image where the problem is visible after zooming in]

Comment: Flexbox or position: relative/absolute will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to apply `display: flex;` to the outer div. You can remove `z-index` and `height` from the inner div.

```css
#small_box {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

#border_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="border_box">
  <div id="small_box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work ... The gap will still be there when I zoom in/out in the browser

Comment: works perfectly fine in the snippet even if you zoom in and out.

Comment: I don't know if this is a browser-specific issue, but on chrome it does not work ..

Comment: can confirm your statement, works fine on chrome for me.